# PDO: missing driver on ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, pdo

I have two separeate projects running on same server.
In the first one I'm using PDO and everything is working correctly.

```
   print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers())
```

gives me **mysql** and **pgsql**

In the second project, again I want to connect to DB using PDO, and I get error, that I'm missing a driver. When i try to output getAvailableDrivers:

```
  print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers())
```

I get **sqlite**
So I need to somehow force the second project to use mysql drivers.

+possible important information: In the second project I'm using my own namespace, therefore in the beginning of script I have to add

```
 use PDO;
```

**EDIT:** result of command

```
 $ aptitude search php5-mysql
```

is

```
 i   php5-mysql                                         - MySQL module for php5
 p   php5-mysqlnd                                       - MySQL module for php5 (Native Driver)
```

Comment: why don't you search for `pdo` ?

Comment: There is no PHP PDO package in Ubuntu, the PDO MySQL libraries are in the php5-mysql package.

Comment: How are your projects separated? Separate httpd instances? Different directories on the same instance?

Comment: well one project is a REST api, which is subdirectory project/API (for example). The second project is websocket related (is running in loop) and is located in project/socket. I am not quite sure what you mean by httpd instance (linux newbie here)

Comment: I have the same issue. I installed

    php5-mysql 

but 

    php --ri pdo
    
    PDO support => enabled
    PDO drivers => sqlite

Comment: I still havent find any solution, so If you find any, let me know please :-)